# Does compact set have always content

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

A set is said to have content iff it's boundary have content zero.

So does  compact set have always content?

I can't really find a way to proof this, but for all examples that I can think of

(cantor set, {1,1/2,1/4,1/8...} ) that have weird behaviors and compact, they have content.

Comment: What does "content" mean?

Comment: A set is said to have content iff it's boundary have content zero. definition of content zero is here http://www.math.wisc.edu/~angenent/376.2005/zerocontent-problems.pdf

Comment: Okay, so what you are referring to is called "Jordan content" or "Jordan measure"

Answer (score 2):

The set $[0,1]$ is compact, but has non-zero content. The set $\{0\} \cup \{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}$, on the other hand, is compact with zero content. You might also want to verify that any finite set is compact with zero content.

The cantor set is an example of a compact set with non-zero content.  Note also that the Cantor set is equal to its own boundary.

Comment: Yes, but the question here is not whether a set have content zero or not. it's does it have content, or does it's boundary always have content zero. in the case of [0,1], the boundary set {0,1} have content zero just like {0}∪{1,1/2,1/3,…}

Comment: See my latest edit.